# Proxying HTTPS request is not working when adjusting response in custom plugin

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I have a custom plugin where I want to adjust upstream response (call…enable_buffering(), and adding JSON to HTTP response during body_filter phase). I created new route and upstream to handle HTTPS endpoints, but Kong is triggering an error when I try to test my API through Kong proxy: I got following error in Kong:

> buffered proxying cannot currently be enabled with http/2, please use
> http/1.x instead, client: 172.18.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET
> /api/target?roomName=1…

Please how can I proxy HTTPS request through Kong and adjust upstream response accordingly?

Find below more details:

```
#route → service
/api/target/-> /upstreamService

#https request not working through kong
curl -kv --get --location ‘https://localhost:8443/api/target?roomName=1’
```

server logs:

```
/kong/plugins/custom-auth/handler.lua:105: buffered proxying cannot currently be enabled with http/2, please use http/1.x instead, client: 172.18.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /api/target?roomName=1

#https working request , forcing http1.1:

curl --get -kv --location --http1.1 ‘https://localhost:8443/api/target?roomName=1’
result success response 200

#enable buffering in access phase
kong.service.request.enable_buffering()
```

Comment: The message suggest this is a limitation of Kong when using HTTP/2.

Comment: yeah, a limitation in kong